# Javascript constructor/OOP

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to recreate this:
https://ibb.co/hh45jH

`new Box(0, 0, 20, 30, "#007", parentDiv)`

doesn't produce anything at all and I'm not quite sure why. I want it to produce a colored div with the above specifications

This is my code so far:

```js
class Box {
  constructor(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, backgroundColor, parentElement) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = width;
    div.style.height = height;
    div.style.background = backgroundColor;
    style.position = "absolute";
    style.top = yPosition;
    style.left = xPosition;
  }

  function draw() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
    new Box(0, 0, 20, 30, "#007", parentDiv)
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", draw);
```

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv"></div>
```

I want the above JavaScript code to produce a new div with the given instructions (color, height, width and so on) and then place it in the parentDiv just like in the example (link above).

Comment: Can you recreate a code snippet describing your problem? Your question is not clear, what bugs/problems do you have?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Just click the `<>` snippet editor and add code that shows the output and tell us the expected output

Comment: new Box(0, 0, 20, 30, "#007", parentDiv) doesn't produce anything at all and I'm not quite sure why. I want it to produce a colored div with the above specifications

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please see the console output and fix it

Comment: You have undefined style and the code runs if you move the function draw out of the class. `var div = document.createElement("div");
    var style = div.style;`

Comment: @MrMeeseeks Your `Box` constructor does just create a `div` element, and then throws it away - it does not do anything with it. It also does not create a single property on the Box instance. Shouldn't you use the `parentElement` parameter for anything?

Comment: You also define a class="parentDiv" but use getElementById

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes to your snippet. Check this out and fell free to comment if you have any doubt

```js
class Box {
  constructor(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, backgroundColor) {
    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    var style = this.element.style;
    style.width = width + "px";
    style.height = height + "px";
    style.background = backgroundColor;
    style.position = "absolute";
    style.top = yPosition;
    style.left = xPosition;
  }
}

function draw() {
  let parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
  let newBox = new Box(0, 0, 20, 30, "#557");
  parentDiv.append(newBox.element);
}


window.addEventListener("load", draw);
```

```css
#parentDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv"> asd </div>
```

Comment: There's no good reason why `Box` should be a `class`. Just make it a `function` that returns the `element`.

Comment: agree, but changing things too much could lead the OP to a more difficult understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on my snippet, after you define your class properly, you can create an object by this class and use a function from this object to draw it like that.

```js
class Box {
  constructor(xPosition, yPosition, width, height, backgroundColor) {
    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.element.style.width = width+"px";
    this.element.style.height = height+"px";
    this.element.style.background = backgroundColor;
    this.element.style.position = "absolute";
    this.element.style.top = yPosition;
    this.element.style.left = xPosition;
  }
  
  draw(){
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentID");
  var newBox = new Box(0, 0, 20, 30, "#007");
  parentDiv.append(newBox.element);
  }
}

const newBoxObj = new Box();


window.addEventListener("load", newBoxObj.draw());
```

```html
<div id="parentID"></div>
```